# android cannot hide the bottom sheet completely samsung-s21

Tags: android, bottom-sheet, samsung-galaxy

Bottomsheet does not hide completely. This only happens on Samsung S21 devices. Does anyone have any ideas or come across a similar situation?

**My Code:**

```
    quickMenuSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheetLayout);
    quickMenuSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN); //default set state
    quickMenuSheetBehavior.setHideable(true);
```

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fl_bottom_sheet_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/bottom_sheet_bottom_sheet_container_frame_layout_padding_end"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/bottom_sheet_bottom_sheet_container_frame_layout_padding_start"
        app:behavior_hideable="true"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Problem:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaHbr.png)

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please include some screenshots of the problem?

Comment: @AnantaRaha I added screenshots. Bottomsheet stays down as in the photo.